# Nodes and edges columns in dataframe to build a network

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am facing difficulties in reproduce visually the following data:

```
     Nodes                            Edges
0   342                              [342]
1   7564                             [7564]
2   21                               [21]
3   43                               [43, 24,4346]
4   4346                             [4346,43]
... ... ...
74  24                               [24,43]
```

This dataset includes nodes and information on edges between nodes. Specifically, in the brackets there are edges between a node and another node (or just itself).
For instance:

node `43` has three edges with itself, node `24` and node `4346` respectively. Node `24` has only two edges, one with itself and another with node `43`; same for node `4346`. Node `342`, node `7564` and node `21` have only edges with themselves.
I would like to have a chart/network which can show these relationships.
Unfortunately I am not able to create edges using the information within the brackets (in pandas column), but only nodes. I am using *Networkx*. I hope you can help me and explain me how to create links between nodes, considering the relationships described in Edges column.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need first `explode` the list column then create the network with `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx
df = df.explode('Edges')
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Nodes', 'Edges')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help @YOBEN_S. I have tried to plot it by `nx.draw(G)`   but I got this error: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'is_numlike'`. Could you please let me know if you have problem to visualise the results as a graph?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html\

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but the first case (probably that one should I consider) is `draw(G[, pos, ax])`. I do not know what I should put witting square brackets.Do you think the error its because I am missing that part?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro that maybe the reason ~